# How to enable mDNS on Windows (7)

Tags: windows-7, networking, mdns

What do I need to get multi-cast DNS on Windows (7) including the Windows box announcing its name in the `.local` domain?

I am not so much interested in the service discovery part. It would be nice bonus, but what I need is the computers to be able to refer to each other by *name*. They have dynamic IP addresses assigned, but the router does not support DNS.

The only things I could find with Google and looked somewhat official is "Bonjour *print services*", which is not obvious whether it is what I need. And then there is a bunch of downloads of various versions where I can't verify whether they are valid.

Note that mDNS works fine for the computers attached on the network so while it would be possible to find another solution, getting mDNS on the Windows box is strongly preferred.

Comment: So is your actual question/problem 'how to enable mDNS in Windows', or 'how do I get machine discoverable by name on an ad-hoc network'?   If it's just about enabling mDNS, then what have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?  If it's about getting them to resolve, and you have an actual .local "Domain" then why not just use a regular DNS server?  Perhaps edit your question to also include an explanation of the network setup beyond "Ad-hoc" as it helps paint a picture for people formulating answers. What types of computers?  What OSs?  What types of connections? etc.

Comment: @techie007: Ad-hoc means it's connected to a router that provides (dynamically allocated) DHCP but no DNS. mDNS works fine on the computers present so far. The operating system of those where it works does not matter as the protocol is always the same; it only matters the one where it does not is Windows 7.

Comment: this is why I ask for clarification. ;)  "Ad-hoc" means there is no infrastructure (like the router you are now mentioning).  Now that we know it exists:  if your run-of-the-mill router can run DD-WRT or alike, then you could use DNSMasq to act as a DNS server on the router.

Comment: @techie007: The router runs some preinstalled firmware. I definitely don't consider flashing it an easier option.

Comment: @grawity: Yes, that question seems to be the same and does have an applicable answer.