# How to enable mDNS on Windows 10 build 17134?

Tags: windows-10, bonjour, windows-10-v1803, mdns

I am looking for a way to resolve .local addresses in Windows 10.

Windows itself also includes mDNS support, but that appears to only be available for Modern API applications.

In the past, the advice has always been to install Apple's Bonjour, for instance [How to enable mDNS on Windows (7)](https://superuser.com/questions/705489/how-to-enable-mdns-on-windows-7). Unfortunately, that seems to no longer be working.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that one of Windows' own processes, DNSCache, is now listening on port 5353.

How do I get mDNS to work for non-Modern applications?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer minutes after posting my question.

The solution is to first disable mDNS in Windows. This has to be done in the registry. As usual, the standard warning applies: editing the registry is not for the faint of heart, and doing it incorrectly can damage your Windows installation beyond repair.

Navigate to the registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient. If the key does not exist, you may need to create it.

Then add the value EnableMulticast as a REG_DWORD, with the value 0.

Reboot.

Then install Bonjour. After this hack, mDNS works as expected.

Update: In recent versions (tested on Windows 10 10.0.19042), it appears that Windows resolves mDNS for all applications out of the box, without needing a registry hack or Bonjour at all. I tested it on the Pro version, and do not know if it applies to the Home version as well.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Just to clarify you need to *reinstall* bonjour if you already have it installed after changing the registry.

Comment: I wrote a program that used mDNS, and was confused why it only sometimes worked.  Adding the registry hack above seems to have fixed it.  Do you know: what does DNSCache do?  What side effects might disabling it have?  Is there a way to play nicely with it on an un-hacked windows install?

Comment: The entry is DNSClient, not DNSCache. It disables the mDNS implementation that Windows itself provides. See the answer from Teocci for details. The problem with the Windows implementation is that it is only available to Universal applications, but not to Win32 applications, which is most of it. At the same time, it does listen on port 5353, which prevents Bonjour from running. So once you free up port 5353 by disabling Microsoft's limited implementation, you can then run Bonjour and get the full benefit of mDNS.

Comment: @KevinKeane: UDP can have multiple listeners on the same port. (Actually so can TCP, but usually not by default). See [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/mdns-in-the-enterprise/ba-p/3275777). That said, I still have some problems with Bonjour. : - /

Comment: @NickWestgate I think this article is misleading. Although it claims "listening" note that the other processes in the example would actually be using the same port for sending (i.e., advertising themselves on mDNS). Multiple senders on the same port is possible (for UDP). Only one process can be listening at a time, because otherwise the TCP/IP stack wouldn't know where to deliver incoming packets. Also see http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-4.html - question 4.5.

Comment: @KevinKeane It might break things, but it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694148/313445).

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Group Policy Home for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 documentation](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DNSClient::Turn_Off_Multicast) you have to ***Turn off the Link Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR)*** using the `DNSClient::EnableMulticast` policy setting.

You can disable the LLMNR if you enable the DNSClient::EnableMulticast policy setting by following these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` in the ***Open*** box, and then click ***OK***.
2. If prompted by ***User Account Control***, click ***Yes*** to open the ***Registry Editor***.
3. Locate and then click the `DNSClient` subkey in the registry path:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\`
4. If the `DNSClient` subkey does not exits create a new Registry Key by Right-click on `Windows NT` subkey.
5. Select ***New*** and then ***Key***
6. Name it as `DNSClient`.
7. Right-click on `DNSClient` subkey.
8. Select ***New*** and then ***DWORD (32-bit) Value***
9. Name it as `EnableMulticast`.
10. Double-click on `EnableMulticast` to edit the value with `0`
11. Reboot your PC.

If this process is to long create a batch file and run it as administrator:

1. Create an `enable_mdns.bat` file using your favorite text editor.
2. Copy and paste this snippet:

```sh
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" /V "EnableMulticast" /D "0" /T REG_DWORD /F
```

3. Save it and Run it as administrator.
4. If prompted by ***User Account Control***, click ***Yes*** to run the `.bat` file.
5. Reboot your PC.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the batch file is definitely the simpler proposition.