# mDNS / DNS-SD on Windows 10 stops working when the network change

Tags: windows-10, mdns

I was trying to discover services through DNS-SD protocol. To enable it on Windows 10 (version 1909), I followed this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1330027/how-to-enable-mdns-on-windows-10-build-17134). However, after the network change, it stops working. No matter you try to reconnect to the old network and reboot.

To recover, I had to change the following registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient\EnableMulticast
```

from 0 to 1 or vice-versa. I have observed this behavior on 4 Windows machines updated to the last version (1909).

To better understand the problem, I've installed Wireshark to observe ingoing/outgoing packets. When I switch the network, I stop seeing incoming packets related to mdns, but I continue to see outgoing packets.

What's going on? Is this a bug or a misconfiguration?

NOTE: I've also tried to DISABLE the firewall, but it doesn't solve anything, the incoming packets are missing