# How to continually run mDNS on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bonjour, mdns

I'm facing issues enabling mDNS in Windows 10.

I've implemented the solution provided in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1330027/how-to-enable-mdns-on-windows-10-build-17134) and it works, but after running PC 24 hrs it vanishes and Bonjour Services can't find any mDNS locals:

**A graphic of a blank BonjourServices window**

[image: IMG:]

Running Service Browser app on my phone found mDNS locals :

[image: IMG:]

Restarting the PC is the only solution I have now.

Note: I Always use windows Sleep instead of Shutdown. Sleep does not prevent Bonjour Services from finding mDNS locals.

I hope the following PC info helps :

[image: Windows info Screenshot]

Comment: I thought Windows 10 finally got its own built-in mDNS support and doesn't require Apple's Bonjour Services for Windows any more.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Spiff, However both cases whether I run Bonjour or not, The software I'm using can't find mdns locals (when it's considered not working). And the software(s) can find mdns locals (when it's considered working).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable mDNS on Windows 10 build 17134?](https://superuser.com/questions/1330027/how-to-enable-mdns-on-windows-10-build-17134)

Comment: @Run5k, It's different, I'm up-to-date with the answers provided there.

Comment: There are two similar questions on superuser.com [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1599673/reset-mdns-service-on-windows-10-without-rebooting) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1507290/mdns-dns-sd-on-windows-10-stops-working-when-the-network-change). and I am facing the exact same issue. After some time or afeter network change mDNS stops working and only a restart makes it work again.

Comment: See the last entry in [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/101168/mdns-not-sending-queries-to-the-network.html): "Basically will multicast stop to work if your wifi has any issues. Can only be resolved by disabling/enabling the interface, reboot machine (or toggle the ipv6 setting)". You could try to disable IPv6 in the local network, and see if disabling/enabling the network interface resolves the problem once it arrives.

Comment: ...Another idea would be to give the computer a static IP address, in case the problem arrives when the DHCP lease is renewed.

Comment: Has everyone abandoned this post?

Comment: Not clearly, I'm receiving notifications but I'm focusing on a project. I'll return once I have time for it.

Comment: @harrymc, I've made a small test to replicate the issue and resolve it: by reconnecting to WiFi. the .local is no longer reachable, However by disable-then-enable wifi interface, It Does again!..EDIT: Until I confirm, It's unstable here.

Comment: It seems that my first comment had the correct explanation. Is it good enough for an answer?

Comment: I can confirm that when the issue occurred (by deliberate reconnection to WiFi router), I can fix it by either Checking/Unchecking IPv6, or by Disabling/Enabling WiFi interface.

Comment: @harrymc, Yes, It's enough! Please submit it

Comment: The answer is submitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final comment in the post
[MDNS not sending queries to the network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/101168/mdns-not-sending-queries-to-the-network.html)
says:

> This is most likely a known windows bug regarding multicast routing.
> Chased this issue for a year until finally Intel and Microsoft teamed
> up and gave this reply:
>
> *The engineering team has investigated this multicast issue with Microsoft. Microsoft is aware there's an issue with the multicast
> address managed by the OS. The issue has been introduced together with
> Windows 10 (WDI arch for WiFi Drivers.) Any scenarios of WLAN
> reconnected (i.e. Airplane mode, roaming out and back into RF range,
> or disconnect and reconnect to the same SSID) and then the multicast
> packets might be affected by this issue. Currently this issue is
> expected to be fixed for Windows 10 Version 21H1.*
>
> **Basically will multicast stop to work if your wifi has any issues. Can
> only be resolved by disabling/enabling the interface, reboot machine
> (or toggle the ipv6 setting).**

The problem here is with WiFi disconnection not being reestablished
automatically.
This is a bug with Windows which will (hopefully) be fixed in the next Windows
release in the first half of 2021.

In the meantime, you might investigate the cause for WiFi disconnections,
perhaps a problem of the hardware, of the working conditions or software/firmware
not being up to date. You could also try to disable IPv6 in your local network.
If nothing is found or can be improved, you will need to
wait for the next Windows release.