# Reset mDNS service on Windows 10 without rebooting

Tags: windows-10, mdns

#### Summary

Sometimes multicast DNS (mDNS) on my Windows 10 desktop gets hung up and doesn't resolve the names of other devices on the network.

I am connecting to SSH and web services running on several Raspberry Pi 3 B+ devices that I've installed the `avahi-daemon` on, so that they respond to mDNS requests. On a normal day, this works perfectly fine, but sometimes when I resume from sleep / hibernate in Windows 10, I get the following result.

As soon as I reboot my Windows 10 OS, mDNS magically starts working again.

```
PS> ssh username@device.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname device.local: No such host is known.
```

```
PS> curl device.local:8080
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: device.local
```

#### Question ❓❓❓

**Is there a way to reset the mDNS service without rebooting Windows 10 completely?**

I can't find any related services except for `Dnscache`.

```
PS> gsv | ? name -match dns

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  Dnscache           DNS Client
```

#### Actual Result

Hostname is not resolved

#### Expected Result

Hostname is resolved, and SSH and/or web connection is established.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you’re using mDNS name resolution? Because IIRC Windows does not have that built-in.

Comment: @DanielB: It actually does as of Windows 10.1803 (approximately), though it is [off by default](https://superuser.com/questions/1330027/how-to-enable-mdns-on-windows-10-build-17134), so it's still more likely that OP is using LLMNR (which _is_ also multicast DNS, even though different from 'mDNS'). Both are handled by Dnscache. But it's also slightly possible that OP uses mDNS through Bonjour installed as part of iTunes.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: We need more information to understand your setup and problem symptoms.

Comment: @harrymc Updated. The symptom is failure to resolve mDNS addresses. The question is: how do I reset the mDNS stack on Windows, without rebooting?

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this by disabling & enabling the Wifi network adapter

You can refer to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1634246/126182) answer for some more details